# SAP UI 5 table column

Tags: sapui5

How can I hide/show a table column on the click of button.

e.g. [Check Here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview)

I need to hide/show the Price column on the click of external button.

Comment: On click of the button set the column visibility to false.

Comment: Show your code that you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can access table column and then set property as follows.

```
var tab= this.getView().byId("idProductsTable");
col=tab.getColumns()[5];
tab.getColumns()[5].setProperty("visible",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();

        var oProduct=new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Product"}),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text:"TExt"
            })
        });

        var oPrice=new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Price"}),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text:"price"
            })
        });
        oTable.addColumn(oProduct);
        oTable.addColumn(oPrice);

        //Button

        var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"Button",
            press:function(){
                oPrice.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

This will surely Help